# Difference between "entscheiden" and "beschließen"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Is there any differences between *entscheiden* and *beschließen*? Or are they just synonyms? 
I translate them as *to decide*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Entscheiden* is often used if you have a personal decision to make where you have different options to choose from.

*Beschließen* is more like a collective decision where a group of people decide on something together. It has an official character.

But many people use them as synonyms, anyway.